# Open-Source English Dictionary - Python - library - API

Tags: python, api, python-2.7

Is there an online dictionary/ library one can consult that stores all english words.
So for instance if I want all words that start with letter 'a' or if I want english words that have 9 letters ...etc 
Do you know of any API support written in python?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

If you are using *nix environment, you can always refer

```
/usr/share/dict/
/var/lib/dict/
```

Answer (score 1):

While it is not open source, if you are looking for an API, take a look at Wordnik. It has a [API](http://developer.wordnik.com/docs) for the Dictionary. Check out their [Developer console](http://developer.wordnik.com/docs) to live test the API methods.

They have [client libraries](http://developer.wordnik.com/) in a variety of languages including [Python](https://github.com/wordnik/wordnik-python).